# French, English and Japanese data With React (web)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, react-hooks

Hi I am trying figure out how to structure my website with multiple languages(English, French and Japanese). I am working on it as a volunteer and I'd like to know how basic webpages with multiple language do to switch language without translating word by word. I'm working with React.js (+ MUI and react-router).

Any suggestions how to structured a code to output a text component with the selected language?

If possible, some best practices

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you are using react, have a look at [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com). It offers internationalization functionalities that are easily accessible via hooks.

The basic principle is to have some language/translation files that can be just JSON files including keys and their corresponding translations in a certain language.

The library can then be told where to load those files and which file to use depending on the selected language. You can also set it up to detect the preferred browser language by default and has more sophisticated options as well.